# Non-UML diagrams to show objects and their creation

Tags: uml

I am trying to understand new piece of project. I am drawing UML class diagrams, but there is something missing for me in these diagrams: the creation of objects. What a traditional UML diagram can depict is how these classes are related to each other and how instances of these classes are related to other objects of other classes, but that is in the moment when they are already created. Sometimes it is not that obvious who creates who, sometimes it is totally misleading. For example objects of class A may create object of class B, but that A object just returns this B object and gives it to somebody else and doesn't hold any reference to it. And sometimes it holds (a reference or pointer). Sometimes it matters for the reader. So in fact there are two types (pieces) of information: holding and creating. I came up with my own way of visualizing this, but maybe there is something standard here? What do you think? And I don't have UML Object diagram in mind, that is not something very helpful when reading C++ or Java code and trying to understand the relation of classes and objects. And not sequence diagram also, that's a different kind of beast.

Comment: Do you use a specific software methodology in software development?

Comment: Hm... I don't understand your question. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: For example : RUP based methodologies, or Agile based or Scrum or something else.

Comment: Also, did you check the Communication and Sequence Diagram and their applications in communicating between objects? Or you want something else?

Comment: I work in Scrum, but does it make any difference? Code is code, I have to get to know it before I start coding some new features. As far as the sequence diagrams are concerned I added above just a minute ago that this is also not something I would like to use when familiarizing with some unknown code.

Comment: OK, thanks, I am **only** thinking  for a solution based on methodology. For example in our projects we follow the steps of our methodology in Analysis and Design. And we **split** all our diagrams based on our **Use Cases** (actor requests). So we do not encounter something similar to your problem. **Maybe** you are trying to model many concepts of programming in one diagram of UML.

Comment: Maybe. I am just trying to be pragmatic. Spending a lot of time time to prepare all kinds of UML diagrams is not an option. Let's say that I have just a day or two to understand the code and start coding. I want to take a sheet of paper and draw something usfeul. A combination of class diagram and some unknown diagram presenting creation of objects. I am doing it my way so far, it works for me, but I just wonder how other people do this.

Comment: Yeah, draw something useful. Maybe in 100 years it will be worth 1 million bitcoins. Read what Euclid said to Ptolemy about maths. Design is the same.

Comment: Bitcoins will by then be only a painful memory. Like tulip mania a few centuries ago: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulip_mania

Comment: Guess why I said 1 million.

Comment: I think you’re wanting to express behaviour here rather than structure, particularly the behaviour of instances rather than of classes. Gholamali-Irani is right I think — you need a separate model e.g interaction or communication to show this. If you’re compelled to use only class diagrams you could use stereotyping and tagged values to extend the meaning of certain relationships but I doubt it would be clear to anyone other than yourself, so if you want to use these for communication with others I’d avoid that.

Comment: I'm surprised about your apparent  unwillingness to consider sequence diagrams as they are an excellent way of documenting what happens in your program. And this is something I often do when trying to understand complex C++/Java code: create classes using class diagrams, create activities for local operations/methods, create sequence diagrams for using an operation from another class, combine fragments when creating a global overview of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to class diagrams, you can use the «create» usage dependency from UML Standard Profile (chapter 22 of UML 2.5 specs).

> «Create» | Usage | A usage dependency denoting that the client classifier creates instances
>   of the supplier classifier.

So e.g. here A creates an instance of B, and C just has a reference to B.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I think this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A [type of UML diagrams](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-uml/) show only one particular view of your system by abstracting the other aspects of a system. For example, a [class diagram](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-class-diagram/) shows only the static aspect of the system, but not the dynamic behavior such as:

> At what time an object was created

The central ideas of modeling a system is trying to deal with (or focus on) an aspect at a time, and at the same time to eliminate the complexity by forget about the other aspects of a system.

In this case, "creating an object at a particular time by who (another object)" should be dealt with behavior view, thus, we can use a [sequence diagram](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-sequence-diagram/) to modeling the dynamic behavior:

[image]

You can see the Dimension of a sequence diagram in the Figure:

1. Horzontally, Objects Lifecycle
2. Vertically, Time

You might then be interested, how I can relate these models together? Will there be any inconsistencies among them? Right! if you are puzzling about this, you are in the right track!

Look! models are inter-connected each other, take an example, you can create a [use case](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-use-case-diagram/), and a use case can be detailed with a number of scenarios, then.. each scenario can be modeled by a sequence diagram, and the sequence diagram giving you the hints of what objects (and what operations and attributes in it) you need to build your systems, right?

[image]

Comment: You are right about this all, but... you live in a perfect world. Of course it would be great to give yourself weeks of time to draw all those beuautiful diagrams and then look at them and understand the system. But in a situation of an ordinary developer who enters a new project and has to QUICKLY implement a user story, that is not an option. He or she will not draw all those diagrams, instead will sketch something quick to put all the pieces of software at once on a sheet of paper and get confidence with the overall design. That was something I was searching for when I asked this question.